Rust macro token tree parameter doesn't work with array accessing expressions
I have made the following macro:
#[macro_export]
macro_rules! quick_match {
    ( $expression:expr, $( $x:tt ),* ) => {
        {
            match $expression {
                $( $x => true, )*
                _ => false,
            }
        }
    };
}

I try to call it in main like so:
mod macro_tests;

fn main() {
    let a = 0;
    let list = vec![1,2,3,4,5,0];

    let test = quick_match!(a, list[0]);
}

And this is the error I get back:
error: no rules expected the token `[`
 --> src\main.rs:7:36
  |
7 |     let test = quick_match!(a, list[0]);
  |                                    ^ no rules expected this token in macro call
  |
 ::: src\macro_tests\macros.rs:2:1
  |
2 | macro_rules! quick_match {
  | ------------------------ when calling this macro
  |
  = note: while trying to match `,`

Can someone help me? I don't know why this is happening, so if someone could explain to me that would be nice.
Thanks in advance.
P.S I initially tried to use expr instead of tt in x, but then it would tell me that it does not allow arbitrary expressions in patterns, whatever that means.

What should quick_match!(a, list[0]) expand to?

it should expand to a match statement

To this? That doesn't work. What exactly should quick_match!(a, list[0]) expand to?

Yeah i realized that doesnt work later. I ended up realizing that it just wont work like that so i made x be an expr instead and that's all

Why use a match/pattern over if and ==? Or rather just == if you're only returning true/false? If that isn't the true goal, perhaps you're trying to re-implement matches!?
